# Notify by email when passenger error occurs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

is it possible to send notification emails when passenger error occurs? Something similar to the email sending by exception notifier when there is an error in Rails app.

I wonder because now we have no way to find out if someone hits an unexpected app spawner or other error (like memory limit etc.).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As well as a basic notifier plugin, there are a couple of excellent services that do notifications and more.

Check out:

- http://github.com/rails/exception_notification
- http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/home
- http://www.getexceptional.com/

Comment: These services catch errors related to *Rails stack*. I think foresth was referring to Passenger errors (like memory management errors).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for server monitoring software.

For example, if your server is running Linux, [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) might work. From their website:

> Monit is a free open source utility for managing and monitoring, processes, programs, files, directories and filesystems on a UNIX system.

According to the documentation, Monit can monitor server processes, which would presumably include Passenger. In the event of an issue, it could restart the Passenger process(es) and/or send a notification.